# Prawn + Russian fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn, cyrillic

I have a Rails app and I use Prawn gem there. I need to make it to generate pdf with Russian alphabet (mix of Russian and English words, in fact). I did a research and found some time ago it was fairly tricky. What about it now, how do I do that?

```
def about
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = Prawn::Document.new
        pdf.text "не ну ни фига sebe"
        send_data pdf.render
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have a try, doesn't matter if it is broken, and put your code in the question. It will be easier to help when we can see how you are using fonts and character encoding (one or both may need to change).

Comment: @NeilSlater, has it helped you?

Comment: Yes I can get a fault - all Russian alphabet characters appear as underscores. But the good news is that it has the right number of characters, so this is just a font issue (prawn does the right thing with character encoding).

Comment: @NeilSlater, what do I do? I added `# encoding: utf-8` to a controller's file, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with fonts, you need to install a font that supports the characters you wish to display, and tell `prawn` to use it.

`prawn` version 0.12.0 comes with one font which will at least display something:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.font "#{Prawn::BASEDIR}/data/fonts/gkai00mp.ttf"
pdf.text "не ну ни фига sebe"
send_data pdf.render
```

If you want it prettier, you need to find and use another font, and modify the `pdf.font` line to use it.

Comment: after I install it, what do I do: call pdf.font? if yes, what do I do on the server (heroku)?

Comment: @Marius Kavansky: yes, you may want to search for a nice font. It's not easy to recommend one. Microsoft used to give away some decent fonts with wide Unicode support for free download (the Times New Roman ttf had very nice Unicode support). But nowadays it seems they are considered part of a product bundle, so may not be available to you for free.

Comment: @Marius Kavansky: probably easiest with a downloaded font is to add the font file to a folder in your repo, and load it using a different path. The `#{Prawn::BASEDIR}` is only for the fonts that come with `prawn`.

Comment: thanks, that's a nice solution. by the way, what folder is it better to put a font in: lib, public, something else?

Comment: @Marius: I don't really know which is best for a Rails project. I probably would not use `public` because there is no need to serve out the font file. Possibly I would choose `lib/fonts`, or `vendor/fonts`