# How to write languages like hindi in a pdf file?

Tags: ruby, encoding, prawn, hindi

I have downloaded a text file which is in Hindi. I want to convert it into pdf. For that I'm using prawn gem. But, the gem is not converting hindi characters at all. It is just converting english characters.

Comment: This could be an issue with fonts - see my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032092/prawn-russian-fonts

Comment: I found the solution later. But, how do I read a file and write every line in a pdf when I do something like File.read("abc.txt").each do |row| text row end ;; it is showing garbage in pdf

Comment: I think you need to put the code, the input file, and the example "garbage" in your question. Also, do you know encoding of text file?